# How to get value from Encode json data on php pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I try to take object from my controller, when I `console.log(response)` it show the value correctly which is in

```
[
    {
    "itemValue":100,
    "itemUnit":"2"
    }
]
```

unfortunately I try to use the object like `response.itemValue` when I console it show `undefined`. I try `var object = response`. during the console it show the same value. Please I want to use the response data.

```
 if(itemID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'?syspath=ajax&controller=ajax&action=getActItemDose',
                data: { 'itemId': itemID, 'itemType': itemType },
                
                
                success:function(response){
                    
                    // var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(response);
                    
                   
                    var object = response;
                    var value = object.itemValue;
                    var unit = object.itemUnit;
                    console.log(object);
                    console.log(value);
                }
            }); 
        }
```

This is controller where I encode the object into Json

```
$row = $getProcess->fetch();


                $object[] = array(
                    'itemValue' => $row['each_dose'],
                    'itemUnit' => $row['unit_dose']
                );
                    echo json_encode($object);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the jQuery library. For parsing JSON, simply do

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
// Accessing individual value from JS object
alert(obj.itemValue); 
alert(obj.itemUnit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` is an array. So you need to access it like

```
response[0].itemValue
```

or you can loop through the array

```
response.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.itemValue);
});
```

Below is the example

```
const response = JSON.parse(`[
    {
    "itemValue":100,
    "itemUnit":"2"
    }
]
`);

response.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.itemValue);
});
```

Comment: I do try with your suggestion. somehow I received undefined when console.log

Comment: it work for the array data ,that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

It worked, by changing this few item

```
$object[] = array();
```

into

```
$object = array();
```

and JSON.parse(data)

```
var object = JSON.parse(data);
value = object.itemValue;
unit = object.itemUnit;
```